# OpenCV::LMSolver getting a simple example to run

Tags: c++, opencv, levenberg-marquardt

**PROBLEM**: The documentation for `cv::LMSolver` at [opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d6d/classcv_1_1LMSolver.html) is very thin, to say the least. Finding some useful examples on the internet, also, was not possible.

**APPROACH**: So, I did write some simple code:

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct Easy : public LMSolver::Callback {
   Easy() = default;

   virtual bool compute(InputArray f_param, OutputArray f_error, OutputArray f_jacobian) const override
   { 
        Mat  param = f_param.getMat();

        if( f_error.empty() ) f_error.create(1, 1, CV_64F);             // dim(error) = 1
        Mat  error = f_error.getMat();                          

        vector<double> x{param.at<double>(0,0), param.at<double>(1,0)}; // dim(param) = 2
        double         error0 = calc(x);
        error.at<double>(0,0) = error0;

        if( ! f_jacobian.needed() ) return true; 
        else if( f_jacobian.empty() ) f_jacobian.create(1, 2, CV_64F); 
        Mat  jacobian = f_jacobian.getMat();

        double e = 1e-10; // estimate derivatives in epsilon environment       
        jacobian.at<double>(0, 0) = (calc({x[0] + e, x[1]    }) - error0) / e; // d/dx0 (error)
        jacobian.at<double>(0, 1) = (calc({x[0],     x[1] + e}) - error0) / e; // d/dx1 (error)
        return true;
   }

   double calc(const vector<double> x) const { return x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1]; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Ptr<Easy>      callback   = makePtr<Easy>();
    Ptr<LMSolver>  solver     = LMSolver::create(callback, 100000, 1e-37);
    Mat            parameters = (Mat_<double>(2,1) << 5, 100);
    solver->run(parameters);
    cout << parameters << endl;
}
```

**QUESTIONS**:

- What does the return value of `LMSolver::Callback::compute()` report to the caller?
- Currently, it finds the minimum at (-9e-07,4e-5), instead of the expected (0.0, 0.0). How can the precision be improved?

Comment: The return value of the callback's `compute()` is simply a boolean representing whether the generation of the jacobian was successful or not. Returning false simply causes the solver to bail out.

Comment: By "precision", do you mean getting more significant digits, or are you asking to get the global minimum instead of the local one the solver lands at?

Comment: The function `x^2 * y^2` only has one minimum, namely `(0,0)`. I can control it in this case by means of the epsilon value. But in my applications `cv::LMSolver` provides much less precise results than `cv::Downhill`. How could I control that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the return value of LMSolver::Callback::compute() report to the caller?

Thankfully, opencv is opensource, so we might be able to figure this out simply by checking out the code.

Looking at the source code [on Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17234f82d025e3bbfbf611089637e5aa2038e7b8/modules/calib3d/src/levmarq.cpp#L91), I found that all of the calls to `compute()` look like:

```
if( !cb->compute(x, r, J) )
    return -1;
```

Returning `false` simply causes the solver to bail out. So it seems that the return value of the callback's `compute()` is simply whether the generation of the jacobian was successful or not.

> Currently, it finds the minimum at (-9e-07,4e-5). How can the precision be improved?

If anything, you should at least compare the return value of `run()` against your maximum iteration count to make sure that it did, in fact, converge as much as it could.

Comment: As mentioned, there is only one minimum in the example function, there is no excuse not to find `(0,0)`.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer Yeah, sorry, I started answering the question with a faulty assumption before you replied to my question. It's corrected to match what you meant to ask.

Comment: so, there is no way to control the precision?

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer `maxiter` and `epsilon` are your only levers provided by the public API. There seems to be a few more internal knobs (for example, there are actually two separate epsilons both set to the value you provide), but there are no exposed ways to access them as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose OP wants to minimize x^2 + y^2 with respect to [x, y].

Because Levenberg-Marquardt method solves a least square problem, the error should be defined as [x, y] so that it minimizes || [x, y] ||^2 = x^2 + y^2.

Another suggestion is that the Jacobian matrix should be provided analytically whenever possible, although this is not crucial in this particular case.

```
struct Easy : public LMSolver::Callback {
   Easy() = default;

   virtual bool compute(InputArray f_param, OutputArray f_error, OutputArray f_j
acobian) const override
   {
        Mat  param = f_param.getMat();

        if( f_error.empty() ) f_error.create(2, 1, CV_64F);             // dim(error) = 2
        Mat  error = f_error.getMat();

        vector<double> x{param.at<double>(0,0), param.at<double>(1,0)}; // dim(param) = 2
        error.at<double>(0, 0) = x[0];
        error.at<double>(1, 0) = x[1];

        if( ! f_jacobian.needed() ) return true;
        else if( f_jacobian.empty() ) f_jacobian.create(2, 2, CV_64F);
        Mat  jacobian = f_jacobian.getMat();

        jacobian.at<double>(0, 0) = 1;
        jacobian.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
        jacobian.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
        jacobian.at<double>(1, 1) = 1;

        return true;
   }
};
```